Como puedo solucionar problemas con el scope de las variables en JavaScript?
Tengo un proyecto en JavaScript donde tengo una variable declarada dentro de una funcion, dentro de esta funcion tengo un for each en el cual le asigno el valor a esta variable pero al intentar usarla con su nuevo valor esta retorna el valor original con el que la declare. El codigo seria algo asi:
function buildList(original){
    let products = []
    original.forEach(item => {
        if(products == []){
            products = [{name: item.name, id: item.id}]
        }else{
            products = [...products, {name: item.name, id: item.id}]
        }
        console.log(products)
    })
    console.log(products)
}

al final de la funcion el console.log retorna [ ] como si no se hubieran hecho cambios pero el console.log que esta dentro del for each si refleja todos los cambios que se hacen

No, el último console.log(products) muestra los mismos elementos que original

Estás haciendo varias cosas que impiden hacer lo que necesitas.
Por ej, estas tratando de comparar si la variable products tiene datos mediante == [], cuando en realidad para saber si un arreglo tiene datos, debes usar length. Al no cumplirse la condición del if, pasa al else, en donde le agregas a products a través de spreads, un nuevo producto que no termina de agregarse.
Aclarado esto, podrías tratar lo siguiente


const agregarProducto = (original) => {
  let lista = [];
  
  original.forEach(item => {    
      if (lista.length === 0) {
        lista.push({ name: item.name, id: item.id });
      } else {
        lista = [ ...lista, { name: item.name, id: item.id }];
      }
  })
  
  console.log(lista)
}

agregarProducto([{ name: 'CR7', id: 1 }, { name: 'Messi', id: 2 }]);



También podrías solucionarlo mediante un map


const agregarProducto = (original) => {
  
  const result = original.map(item => ({ name: item.name, id: item.id }));
  
  console.log(result);
}

agregarProducto([{ name: 'CR7', id: 1 }, { name: 'Messi', id: 2 }]);



Nos comentas cualquier duda :D

Probaste el código del OP??? Porque si bien lo que dices es muy cierto, con el código del OP imprime exactamente lo mismo que tus 2 códigos.

Sí, lo probé y efectivamente muestra los mismos elementos. Mi respuesta fue más orientada a explicar un poco mejor la forma en que se puede implementar la lógica utilizando de manera correcta las funciones y métodos. Quizá la redacción de mi respuesta dio lugar a confusiones.

La respuesta está perfecta. Lo raro está en la pregunta...me lleva a pensar que hay un error en otro lado

Saludos.
Le sugiero usar map; pruebe de la siguiente forma; en lugar de:
original.forEach(item => {
        if(products == []){
            products = [{name: item.name, id: item.id}]
        }else{
            products = [...products, {name: item.name, id: item.id}]
        }
        console.log(products)
    })


La forma (que sé) es la idónea ya que products es un array; debes poblarlo mediante products.push([el dato, objeto o lo que sea será cada elemento]);. De esta forma el if no es necesario, lo que reduce código y lo hace más legible.

use:
let products = original.map((item) => {name: item.name, id: item.id});


Tu respuesta no aporta nada nuevo en relación a la primera respuesta. NO se debe duplicar respuesta. Y además tienes un claro error

Saludos @Yussef no veo tu respuesta acorde a la inquietud de quien solicita apoyo; y claro que esté marcada como solución. Apenas "atinas" a "comentar"; pero como que a aportar no. Hasta entonces, a menos que seas la persona que pide ayuda lo mejor es que aportes guiando para llegar a la solución.

Hola Roberto, no entendí tu comentario. Y para clarificar. (1) Yo no he generado ninguna respuesta a esta pregunta .- (2) La pregunta NO es de convertir un array en otro, es sobre el "scope" de variables, cuyo [MCVE] no muestra problema alguno en ese sentido (3) Tu respuesta no agrega nada nuevo a la respuesta que había anteriormente. (4) Tu respuesta tiene un error, ese código que has puesto no funciona

No recomendaría el map para esta solución. Lo que hace el map es que para cada elemento en el array, la función map crea un nuevo elemento en un nuevo array.
Lo que se erró fue intentar comparar if(products == []). Dos arrays se consideran iguales solo si hacen referencia al mismo objeto en memoria.
Lo que puede resolver esto es usar la función some(), que es específica para arrays y verifica si hay elementos en el array.
Cambiaría esta condición :
if(products == [])

por:
.some(() => true)

Lo que hace es retornar verdadero si hay al menos 1 ítem en el array.
function buildList(original) {
    let products = [];
    original.forEach(item => {
        if (!products.some(() => true)) {
            products = [{ name: item.name, id: item.id }];
            console.log(`Array vacío ${products}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Agregando al array: ${products}`);
            products = [...products, { name: item.name, id: item.id }];
        }
        console.log(products); // mensaje dentro del loop
    });
    console.log(products); // Fuera del loop, muestra el array completo
}

